# [Amazon](600000) Error setting/closing connection: Connection reset by peer. [SQL State=HY000, DB Errorcode=600000]

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

When attempting to COPY large TPCH table data from S3 to my AWS RDS instance I am receiving the following error:

```
An error occurred when executing the SQL command:
copy orders from 's3://aqa-pat/tpchData/tpchRawData/100G/orders.tbl'
credentials 'aws_iam_role=arn:aws:iam::183326689449:role/RedshiftRole'
delimiter ...

[Amazon](600000) Error setting/closing connection: Connection reset by peer. [SQL State=HY000, DB Errorcode=600000] 
1 statement failed.

Execution time: 15m 3s
```

I am running TPCH benchmarks and have created individual table files using TPC's dbgen tools and only receive this connection error on the upload of orders and lineitems tables. The other tables have been loaded.

What should I do to solve this issue? Change the region of my instance to that of the S3 bucket?

Comment: "Execution time: 15m 3s" - if you're running a SQL command that takes that long you're doing something wrong. Find another way to implement it, but sharding for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity, I was loading 100GB of data into a table. I presumed RedShift would be able to handle this load; but reverted to sharding.

I've solved this issue by partitioning my tables into a JSON manifest per the AWS docs.

Here is what the manifest looks like:

```
Copy
{
  "entries": [
    {"url":"s3://mybucket-alpha/2013-10-04-custdata", "mandatory":true},
    {"url":"s3://mybucket-alpha/2013-10-05-custdata", "mandatory":true},
    {"url":"s3://mybucket-beta/2013-10-04-custdata", "mandatory":true},
    {"url":"s3://mybucket-beta/2013-10-05-custdata", "mandatory":true}
  ]
}
```

And here is how to import said manifest into redshift:

```
copy customer
from 's3://mybucket/cust.manifest' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole'
manifest;
```

Here are the docs for anyone else with similar issues:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/loading-data-files-using-manifest.html